# Razor pages jQuery Autocomplete doing nothing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I have implemented the JQuery Autocomplete in the following format:
`AddApplication.cshtml`

```
@page
@model AddApplicationModel
@{

}




<div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="appName" placeholder="Enter Application Name">
            <select asp-items="Model.ministryItems">
                <option>Select Ministry</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Search for a URL" autocomplete="on">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#url").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    console.log("in funct");
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "@Url.Action("GetURL","AddApplication")",
                            data: ({ term: request.term}),
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                            Console.log("success");
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                Console.log("response"+item)
                                return item;
                            }))
                            }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#url").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 0
            }).focus(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When i type something into my textbox nothing happens at all. After some debugging i know for a fact that the function `$("url").autocomplete` is being called, but the `success: function()data{}` is not being hit

Backend razor code:
`AddApplication.cshtml`

```
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetURL(string term)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===============IN GETURL====================");
            System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult result = new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult();


             var list = (from c in db.Url
                        where c.UrlName.Contains(term)
                        select c.UrlName).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(list.Count());

            result.Data = list;
            result.JsonRequestBehavior =  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            Console.WriteLine("---------"+result.Data.ToString());
            return result;
        }
```

`GetURL` I have tested this function with calling it from `OnGet` just to see if it was actually working, and it is successfully querying the data, im not 100% sure if its properly returning the JSONResult. However it is not being called by autocomplete.

I am not sure if this is a path issue, i don't believe it is as i had that resolved beforehand

I have also tried using the following JQuery snippet, and it yields the same results

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    console.log("function");
    $("#url").autocomplete({
        source: "@Url.Action("GetURL","AddApplication")",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
        console.log("-----"+ui.item);
        $("#url").val(ui.item.value);
        $("form").submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Response tab for textbox search

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> - LookupTool</title>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />



        <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/site.js?v=dLGP40S79Xnx6GqUthRF6NWvjvhQ1nOvdVSwaNcgG18"></script>



</head>
<body>
    <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-page="/Index" class="navbar-brand">LookupTool</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav> -->





    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
       <div style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%">




<div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="appName" placeholder="Enter Application Name">
            <select>
                <option>Select Ministry</option>
                <options> - cant display this information
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Search for a URL" autocomplete="on">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#url").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    console.log("in funct");
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "/AddApplication?action=GetURL&amp;controller=AddApplication",
                            data: ({ term: request.term}),
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                            Console.log("success");
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                Console.log("response"+item)
                                return item;
                            }))
                            }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#url").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 0
            }).focus(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            });
        });
    </script>

            <hr />
            <footer>
                footer
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get it working after more searches. Adding the anti forgery token may have been the underlying issue as i did not have it added before. Notice the URL, according to multiple sources this is the correct way to reference a URL in razor.

Although its working for some reason only the completed function is called, it never goes into success. This isnt causing issues at the moment.

`AddApplication.cshtml`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#UrlQueBtn").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $('#urlSelect').val();
            console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
                    url: "AddApplication?handler=AddUrlToQue",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { urlSelect: url },
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        alert("complete")
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Need to add the anti forgery token to startup class
`startup.cs`

under ConfigureServices
`services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `ajax` request to correctly include the query string parameters:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "AddApplication/GetURL",
        data: ({ term: request.term}),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
           response($.map(data, function (item) {
               return item;
               Console.log("response"+item)
           }))
         }
});
```

Comment: Issue still persists with this added. Log inside of success function is still not being hit.

Comment: What browser do you use? Can you go to Dev Tools, on Network Tab and give us the details about the failed request?

Comment: Using chrome right now. [link](https://imgur.com/rtFdIKo) This image shows the network tab. Im getting a 200 ok back and the url is as follows: **AddApplication?action=GetURL&amp;controller=AddApplication&term=sh** sh is the search term, but its clearly not going into the ```success:function()data{}```or else would see a console.log

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Please update the .cshtml with the latest code you have at the moment.

Comment: If possible, attach us also the `Response` tab of the request.

Comment: I've added the requested items

Comment: Can you provide us the `Response` tab also?

Comment: yes I've added it towards the bottom of the original post

Comment: I've changed my answer. Look at the `url` part and at the fact that there is no more `contentType`.

Comment: Originally i had an issue where the path was incorrect. Using the ```url:"AddApplication/GetURL``` results in this incorrect path. I was advised to use ```@Url.Action``` With these changes i am now getting a ```GET AddApplication/GetURL?term= 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: Did you change the routing of the application? Can you provide us the RouteConfig?

Comment: I don't believe i have any routing set up...i am new to razor. Unless a template app comes with a RouteConfig file?

Comment: Can you tell us how did you setup your project?

Comment: I am using VsCode and used the following command ```dotnet new razor```